# Cannot convert value of type 'Data' to expected type 'Data'

Tags: ios, swift

i have a generic function for json parsing

```
static func parseServerResponse<T>(_ type: T.Type, from data: Data)-> T? where T : Decodable{
    do {
        return try JSONDecoder().decode(type, from: data)
    } catch(let error) {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
        return nil
    }
}
```

And it is returning me "Cannot convert value of type 'Data' to expected type 'Data" and on other places where i am using data to return or doing anything with data. why's that so. i have no idea why would it throw a stupid error like that. i have cleaned my project several times, quit xcode and restarted it, updated my pods to no avail. here's a screenshot
[image]

Comment: Do you have a custom type `Data`? You should **not**. Another suggestion: You don't need the *objective-c-ish* `type` parameter, omit it and write `JSONDecoder().decode(T, .....`.  And a method which contains a `throw`ing API is supposed to throw itself handing over the error and return a non-optional.

Comment: i tried your code it's working fine ?